# Updating onclick's string value with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpath, greasemonkey, onclick

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script to update the onclick value of a bunch of links on a page.  The HTML looks like this:

`<a onclick="OpenGenericPopup('url-99.asp','popup',500,500,false)" href="javascript:void(0)">text</a>`

I need to update the `url-99.asp` part of the Javascript into something like `urlB-99.asp`.  In my script, I'm collecting all the links with an XPath expression and iterating through them:

```
var allEl = document.evaluate(
  'td[@class="my-class"]/a',
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
  null);

for (var i = 0; i < allEl.snapshotLength; i++) {
  var el = allEl.snapshotItem(i);
  //something here;
}
```

If I try to `alert(el.onclick)`, I get an error in the console:

`Component is not available`

I've read up on unsafeWindow and other Greasemonkey features, and I understand how to set an event handler for that link with a new onClick event, but how do I read the current onclick value into a string so I can manipulate it and update the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried `el.getAttribute("onclick")` ?

and use `//td[@class="my-class"]/a` instead

Comment: I had completely forgotten I could retrieve and set attributes with `el.getAttribute("onclick")` and `el.setAttribute("onclick", "new text");`.  Thanks!